# How to keep my background image on html file when i make my site public

Tags: html, css, github

So I'm trying to make my site public through github but every time i post it, it deletes my background.

I even have a different file just for my images and used the css tag(background-image: url(../css/resume-background.jpg);) does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does it have any error message or warnings related to the loading of the image
Can you use browser dev tools to inspect the element where the background image should be displayed to identify any issues for more infomation please

Comment: I think you need to put your images in the `public` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some parts. I am also hosting my portfolio website on GitHub.

I using the following HTML code for posting an image:

```
  </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="100"><img class="avatar img-fluid mt-2" src="images/avatar.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="Walter Patterson"/></div>
    </div>
```

Are you facing any issues while uploading to GitHub or while hosting the site via GitHub? If you are facing an issue with hosting your website, could you please share your repo?